# MySQL Date insert

Tags: mysql

I have a date for example in the following format in column A

03/03/2020 01:48:18 pm (Currently Month, Day, Year and 12 hour format for time)

I would like to read the date in Column A and insert into Column B into the following format

2020/03/03/ 13:48:18( Need format Year, Month, Day and 24 hour format)

Would like a query to search for all records in Column A and insert into Column B , row for row

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the second number in 03/03/2020  is the mionth,because that is discernable from your text

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/03/2020 01:48:18 pm", "%d/%m/%Y %r"),'%d,%m,%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Gives you as result

> 03,03,2020 13:48:18